# Extension of Bounded Linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and let $W \subset X$ be a linear subspace. Suppose that $T_W \in B(W,Y)$ and that the range of $T_W$ is finite dimensional.

I know that $T_W$ can be extended to $T \in B(X,Y)$ with $\|T\|=\|T_W\|$. How about the range?